# how to use new Blender 3.5 Ease operator?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

Tried to use the new feature, but the keyframe somehow keep snapped to the center and forming multiple mountain curves. Did I get it wrong?

The one I'm using is from Key>Slider Operator>Ease.

[image]

[image]